# How to shutdown server using Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to shutdown the server from a WAR-deployed Grails application?

Use case: I'm using an application to perform some processing.  When it's done, I want the computer to shutdown (it's running on AWS and I don't want to have it run for longer than needed).

(If there isn't, I'll just set a CPU usage threshold on the AWS monitor and close it down when it drops below a given threshold using AWS's tools, but I'd like a less hacky way of doing it please).

Comment: Can't you just execute a `"shutdown now".execute()`? See: http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/

Comment: I thought about something like that - but does the Tomcat user have shutdown privileges?

Comment: Depends on how you have the user/server configured. I would assume by default, it does not.

Comment: I've tried this in the past. I embedded it in a script and I believe I added the sticky bit to it, which I think makes that particular script run as the owner of the file (which I set to root) and not the executor. Might very well open up some kind of security hole though...

Answer (score 0):

You can get slightly tricky with this- use the AWS SDK to terminate the instance you are running on.

Comment: How would an instance know what instance it actually was, in order to use the SDK?